# Google Sheets - XMLImport Xpath query

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to query orders from Ecwid ecommerce site to a google sheet.

I am using the -ImportXML but my xpath is not working.

XML File - data.xml

Google Sheets
=importxml("data.xml", "//items/item[0-9]/vendorOrderNumber")

I am trying to get a list of each order item0, item1, etc.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put a wild card reference on the item child as vendorOrderNumber is always present (descendant) from it. This query should work for you:

```
=importxml("http://xpeditefulfillment.com/hardmerchandise/data.xml", "//items/*/vendorOrderNumber")
```